# Replacing repetitive words, case-insensitively

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Sample:

```
>>> line = 'the the, To to'
>>> re.findall(r'\b(\w+) \1', line)
['the']
>>> re.findall(r'\b(\w+) \1', line, re.I)
['the', 'To']

>>> re.sub(r'\b(\w+) \1', r'\1', line, re.I)
'the, To to'
```

Expected:

```
'the, To'
```

The regex works in other places like

- Vim: `s/\v<(\w+) \1/\1/gi`
- Perl: `s/\b(\w+) \1/$1/gi`
- sed: `-r 's/\b(\w+) \1/\1/gi'`

Is this a known behavior? What is a workaround? My Python version is `3.4.3` if that makes a difference.

Comment: This isn't really a `perl` question, is it? But the core difference is - you don't seem to have a `gi` modifier in your pattern anywhere.

Comment: @Sobrique the OP has `re.I`, the ignore case flag, and `re.sub` is "global" by default; however, they aren't passing the flag correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [the definition of `re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)

You are passing `re.I` as `count` (where it is allowing at most `2` replacements), not as `flags`. Instead, try:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\b(\w+) \1', r'\1', s, flags=re.I)
                                  # ^ note
'the, To'
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe is there really need to add  word boundry..?

Comment: @ShekharKhairnar I didn't add it, just copied the OP's regex from the question. In this case it doesn't matter, but I assume they're dealing with other cases where it may be relevant.

Comment: yes, in required case, I need to avoid replacing cases like `dot the` - without the `\b` it will change `t t`